# 2-way mini motion sensor (mirror switch)?

Tags: sensor, infrared, proximity-sensor

So a mirror switch will switch ON with 1st "swipe" and OFF on 2nd "swipe". I want to set it up in a 2-way configuration whereby if you pass switch 1 it's ON and then pass switch 2 it's OFF, then pass switch 2 again and it's ON again and so on much like a 2-way lighting circuit. I assume the sensor needs to be a 2-way or can i do this with a 1-way sensor? anyone know anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT0Z2B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. General schematic of a solution.*

Adding a single-pole changeover relay to each switch will make it work like 2-way stair lighting switches.

Note that we have no idea what your switches are, what they are capable of switching and whether they would work properly without the original lighting load.

Comment: this looks great but im having trouble finding one that will do 240v.

Comment: the switches are basicaly mirror light motion sensors i thing they are 240v 1-way switches.

Comment: "*... im having trouble finding one that will do 240v.*" It's 'V' for volt. What are you having trouble with? Finding a 240 V relay? Any of the major suppliers will have them.

Comment: thank chap. the thing is I'm new to working with this kind of thing I am a domestic Installer and I have little experience with relays and such. So even when i type 240V single pole changeover relay into google to shop for the item i want i'm not sure what I'm looking at/for. but i kind of get the drawing above and i recon i would like to have a go at getting this done. So if you could help me by putting some links in, as to what would do the job, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to set up a 2-way sensor switched circuit to turn on 1 LED strip on my stair case simply but. as you step on the lights go on and as you go past the sensor at the top the lights go off, but as you step on from the top they go on and off the bottom they go off. I would like to include a photo cell so that the LED only comes on when it is dark as well. Many thanks

Comment: this sort of sensor I guess.... https://www.astra247.com/infra_red_mini_sensor-switch/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwODlBRDuARIsAMy_28XvB52wpSdOwbvhEr4qfyUUHzCZ41orTrIvb1ijuNM68lluNUavzwgaAifQEALw_wcB

Comment: That seems like the wrong solution and will be prone to getting out of sync and turning the lights *off* when you're on the stairs. Use one or two PIR (passive infrared) motion sensors to detect motion in the area of the stairs. These already have built-in time delays and daylight sensors. Wire them in parallel if using two so that either turns the lights on.